# Assigning variables in Scheme without using set

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, r5rs

I am trying to create a global score in my scheme program and it will either increase by 1, decrease by 1 or not change for each iteration of my function. For example, I have this in my function when I want the score to increase by 1:

```
(set! score (+ score 1)))
```

I am able to do this using set! but I need a way to achieve it without using the set! operation. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Formulate a _state_ datastructure which has a field `score` in it, and for each iteration of the function make a new _state_.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by state. Sorry, I am new to Scheme

Comment: State is everything you need to keep track of. So a game would have GameState with the position of players, score, etc etc. In the "game loop" you create a fresh game state from a previous one, thereby sidestepping the need to mutate global variables.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to realise that you can replace something like this:

```
(define (my-game ...)
  (let ([score 0])
    (some-kind-of-looping-construct
     ...
     (if <not-done>
         (begin
           (set! score <new-score-value>)
           (continue-loop))
         score))))
```

With something like this:

```
(define (my-game ...)
  (define (loop ... score ...)
    ...
    (if <not-done>
        (loop ... <new-score-value> ...)
        score))
  (loop ... 0 ...))
```

In particular you can replace any kind of looping construct which repeatedly assigns to some variable by textually (but not actually) recursive calls to some function which repeatedly binds a variable.

To be concrete about this let's imagine we have a looping construct which looks like

```
(loop exit-fn form ...)
```

So `loop` is the loop construct, and `exit-fn` is the magic thing we call to exit the loop.

And I'll assume there is some function `run-game-round` which takes a round number and the current score, runs a round of the game and returns the new score.

So using this construct we can write the skeleton of some kind of game loop:

```
(let ((round 0)
      (score 0))
  (loop exit
    (set! score (run-game-round round score))
    (set! round (+ round 1))
    (cond
      [(> score 100)
       (exit 'win)]
      [(> round 100)
       (exit 'lose)])))
```

And this is fairly horrible code.

But we can replace this code with this:

```
(begin
  (define (run-game round score)
    (cond [(> score 100)
           'win]
          [(> round 100)
           'lose]
          [else
           (run-game (+ round 1)
                     (run-game-round round score))]))
  (run-game 0 0))
```

And this code does *exactly the same thing* but there is no assignment anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

No `set!`: We can input `list` or given number of args and use function recursive.

```
#lang racket
(define (play-game game-round-lst)
  (local [(define (make-score s)
            (cond
              [(equal? s 'win) 1]
              [(equal? s 'drew) 0]
              [(equal? s 'lose) -1]))]
    (apply + (map make-score game-round-lst))))

;;; TEST
(play-game '(lose win drew lose win)) ; 0
(play-game '(win lose drew win lose win lose)) ; 0
```

Use `set!` **in local function**.
In this method you can build new game without worry about lost state in each game.

```
#lang racket
(define (make-game)
  (local [(define score 0)
          (define (setup-score n)
            (set! score (+ n score)))
          (define (service-manager msg)
            (cond
              [(equal? msg 'win)
               (setup-score 1)]
              [(equal? msg 'drew)
               (setup-score 0)]
              [(equal? msg 'lose)
               (setup-score -1)]
              [(equal? msg 'show-score)
               score]))]
    service-manager))

;;; TEST
(define game1 (make-game))
(define game2 (make-game))
(game1 'win)
(game2 'win)
(game1 'drew)
(game2 'drew)
(game1 'lose)
(game2 'lose)
(game1 'show-score) ; 0
(game2 'show-score) ; 0
```